# EPL Cartridges jammed in HP5550dtn

Tags: printer

I cannot take out the EPL toner cartridges in my HP5550dtn printer. This is a new phenomena as the printer is out of maintenance contract. All four cartridges appear to be jammed. Unfortunately there isnt any reference to this issue in the workshop manual. I have tried several ideas to release the cartridges eg. Switching the printer off. Removing the paper tray.
I suspect it could be a broken gear wheel in one of the cartridges but I dont have any staring references to release the units.
Can anyone advise me on the way to release the system.

Comment: Try  ....   https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printers-Archive-Read-Only/Cartridge-stuck-in-right-side-of-printer-Won-t-move-to/td-p/5750594

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by placing a flat head scewdriver into the left hand side of the cartridge and gently leavering the cog wheel away from the connecting cog. This action released the cartridge. However, I had to repeat this action to temove the other three cartridges.
I dont for one minute believe that I have actually solved the problem, simply found a way to remove the jammed cartridges. I have yet to find out what has caused the mechansim to jam up but I endevour to slove the issue in due course.